# How to document the outcome of an event storming session

Tags: domain-driven-design

It's been a long time since I was first introduced to Event Storming in a DDD workshop. More recently we decided to apply it in practice and we have planned our first sessions with a facilitator (someone from the company who has experience).

The only thing i'm wondering now is how the process AFTER event storming takes place? How does one take the domain knowledge gathered during an event storming session and make sure that it's well documented for other people to consult?

Are there modelling techniques to document the outcome? Do I just take pictures? Should we start the software architecture process straight away and let the code speak for itself?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "As a result, the business process can be seen on the modelling space. But more important is the knowledge that was built in the minds of the participants." Either way, interesting question +1

Answer (score 2):

My answer will not be specific to DDD, but to any session where creative individuals put together facts, spark ideas and work at putting them together into a logical whole.

Try to make reporting a formal process and we know what will happen... somebody will be put in charge of this "boring" task, will put it off and soon the "magic" of the session will be lost in dreary bureaucracy.

In my experience, the only thing I have seen to work is to **make the session its own reporting**. **The key information is recorded during the session itself**, as part of the session.

If you are using a white board or flipchart, or colored stickers, as support for your session, put them to use for that. If you need to record decisions, you need to have a space where those decisions are listed. If you need to record a concept, write it out neatly, or make a neat sketch **during the session**. Then snap a picture and there you are.

If you see measurable added value to it (and this is apparently not called for in an Event Session), you could dematerialize some of these tools. If you meet physically, use a projector to have a common view, while others could use their laptop or tablet to contribute. **You can use a chat tool to write short on-the-spot summaries and keep a running log of key points.** If someone feels like it, they can use a mind map tool (like XMind) to keep the ideas organized (or just draw the mindmap on the white board). If the work is mostly textual, they could edit it together (wiki, Google Docs...). In my experience, all these tools work great if people are not in the same room (in which case you also need some videoconferencing, e.g. Google Hangouts).

But whichever medium you use, the bottomline is that keeping track is part of the duties of the participants during the session. You need to keep **a running record during the session** as you would do the rest: in a collaborative way, and in the most natural way possible. **A creative session that is not wrapped up with a few key points clearly outlined, or a good explicative diagram on some board, is not properly completed and cannot be considered fully productive.**

Then it is up to the leader, or the biggest stakeholder, to make a very brief summary, attach the session's record, and distribute it to the participants through the most adequate channel. That afterwork should ideally be a matter of 10-15 minutes.